# map method not running

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I have an array, I push doc data from firebase into that array and I want to display a table row for each doc. The problem is that the map method won't do anything.

```
const [allScores,setAllScores] = useState([])


async function getAllScores(){
    const q = query(collection(db, "allScores"), orderBy("score", "desc"));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
   /*  allScores.push(doc.data()) */
        allScores.push(doc.data())
})
}
useEffect(() => {
    getAllScores()
}, [])

<table className="text-white text-center">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td className="px-[205px] text-xl">Place</td>
                        <td className="px-[205px] text-xl">User</td>
                        <td className="px-[205px] text-xl">Score</td>
                        <td className="px-[205px] text-xl">Scored at</td>
                    </tr>
                    {allScores.map(score => (
                        place = place + 1,
                        <tr>
                            <td className="px-[205px] text-xl w-auto">{place}</td>
                            <td className="px-[205px] text-xl w-auto">{score.playerName}</td>
                            <td className="px-[205px] text-xl w-auto">{score.score}</td>
                            {/* <td className="px-[210px] text-xl">{score.scoredAt}</td> */}
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to update the state by `setAllScores`

```
async function getAllScores(){
const q = query(collection(db, "allScores"), orderBy("score", "desc"));
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    setAllScores(prev => {
       return [...prev, doc.data()]
    }
 })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can not push to your state, you have to update state by `setAllScores`

```
async function getAllScores(){
    const newAllScores = [];
    const q = query(collection(db, "allScores"), orderBy("score", "desc"));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            newAllScores.push(doc.data())
    })
    setAllScores(newAllScores)
}
```